# selecting all text causing the browser to scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function:

```
function selectAllTextInInputs(textbox) {
    textbox.focus();
    textbox.select();
}
```

and when I call this function with a input element as a paremeter. It do what It meant to do, which is to focus and select the text. But there is one flaw. It scrolls to the top of the page. If I have an element far down on my browser window it scrolls back up to the top of the page. How can I fix so the function doesn't scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the `focus` out from the function. Selecting the content, will automatically give it focus without the scroll.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Y7DRf/1/

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted shouldn't cause to window to scroll to the top AFAIK. How are you calling the selectAllTextInInputs function ? If it's from a `<a>` link, try adding `return false` afterwards to stop it jumping to the top e.g. `<a href="#" onClick="selectAllTextInInputs();return false;">`

Comment: I'm calling it from a div element. And return false doesn't work